# How can I use my void display() to show many input in java?

Tags: java, display

I use **void display()** to show the output. But the result is all for *the last entered element*.Why?
I try to initialize an array in **inputmany** and show it in **void display()** but something wrong. 
Here is my code

```
package atom;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Atom {
    int number;
    String symbol;
    String fullname;
    float weight;

    void inputmany(Atom[] a, int n) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {          
            System.out.print("Enter atomic number : ");number = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter symbol : ");symbol = sc.next();
            System.out.print("Enter full name : ");fullname = sc.next();
        System.out.print("Enter atomic weight : ");weight = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("\n");

    }
}

void display(Atom[] a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println(number + " " + symbol + "  " + fullname + "  " + weight);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Atom[] arr;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter n: ");int n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Atomic Information");
    System.out.println("==================");        
    arr = new Atom[n];
    Atom ob = new Atom();    
    ob.inputmany(arr, n);
    ob.display(arr, n);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you need to explicitly say which `Atom`'s number are you printing out. In your for loop, the correct print would this:

`System.out.println(a[i].number + " " + a[i].symbol + "  " + a[i].fullname + "  " + a[i].weight);`

BUT the problem is not solved yet.

Your println is showing only the last result because the display() method depends on an instance of `Atom` type. If you don't instantiate an `Atom` object, the display() method won't work, like you did here:

> Atom ob = new Atom();
>
> > ob.display(arr, n);

Now the display() method have as reference the ob object, and when you're printing the plain `number`, `symbol`, `fullname` and `weight`, the actual result will be the `ob` attribute values.

Now the real problem starts here:

> ob.inputmany(arr, n);

First of all: you have initialized an **array** of `Atom` types. Now you have to initialize the current `a[i]` object in almost the same way like you did with the array: `a[i] = new Atom()` at the beginning of the for loop.

And as I said before, once you set the value to the plain `number`..`weight` attributes, it will set the value to the current object that you're calling the `inputmany` methods. You need again to specify which object attribute values are you setting:

In your for loop from `inputmany` please change the `number` to `a[i].number` and same for the others.

Here is my approach for your problem :

```
public class Atom {
int number;
String symbol;
String fullName;
float weight;

static void createAtoms(Atom[] a) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = new Atom();
        System.out.print("Enter atomic number : ");
        a[i].number = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter symbol : ");
        a[i].symbol = sc.next();
        System.out.print("Enter full name : ");
        a[i].fullName = sc.next();
        System.out.print("Enter atomic weight : ");
        a[i].weight = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

static void displayAtoms(Atom[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i].toString());
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Atom{" +
            "number=" + number +
            ", symbol='" + symbol + '\'' +
            ", fullName='" + fullName + '\'' +
            ", weight=" + weight +
            '}';
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Atom[] atoms;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter n: ");
    int atomsNumber = sc.nextInt();

    atoms = new Atom[atomsNumber];
    createAtoms(atoms);
    displayAtoms(atoms);

}
}
```

Please pay attention to the `static` keyword which means that there is **no need** of an `Atom` object to call the method. Your methods doesn't need the `int n` parameter because you have the `.length` option to get the array length. And instead of writing all the attributes in your println, you can override the `toString()` method and call it in the for loop for each `Atom`.

**PS**: Please read [naming conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/) . They are very helpful in the future :)

Comment: I've edited the answer because I've missed an important detail : please initialize each `a[i]` object like I said above.

Answer (score -1):

In method `inputmany()` you are setting the new values provide by the user to the same variables, effectively overwriting them.

Why the "same variables"? Because your Atom instance is the same always. This line in `main()` -> `Atom ob = new Atom();`. So, the instance pointed to by `ob` is getting the values always.

### How to solve this

Use this changed class:

```
public class Atom{
    int number;
    String symbol;
    String fullname;
    float weight;

    void inputmany( Scanner sc ){
            System.out.print( "Enter atomic number : " );
            number = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print( "Enter symbol : " );
            symbol = sc.next();
            System.out.print( "Enter full name : " );
            fullname = sc.next();
            System.out.print( "Enter atomic weight : " );
            weight = sc.nextFloat();
            System.out.print( "\n" );
    }

    void display(){
        System.out.println( number + " " + symbol + "  " + fullname + "  " + weight );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        Atom[] arr;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.print( "Enter n: " );
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println( "Atomic Information" );
        System.out.println( "==================" );
        arr = new Atom[n];
        //Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Atom ob = new Atom();
            ob.inputmany( sc );
            arr[ i ] = ob;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Atom ob = arr[ i ];
            ob.display();
        }

    }
}
```

Changes:

1. Here, the `for` loop for collecting details for each `Atom` has been moved to the `main()`. Note that the `Scanner` instance is passed to the `inputmany()` method.
2. Another `for` loop has been added to display the collected values.

Comment: This is not a good approach for the problem. The `Atom[]` parameter for `inputmany()` method is not used, so why pass it ? And the display() method remained the same. How did you solve the problem? Have you executed your code before post the answer? The `display()` for each Atom object isn't a solution for the question.

Comment: @SebastianCăşvean Thanks. You are right, those parameters weren't necessary. I have changed the code now. However, I don't think there is any problem with the approach. The changed code has been tested and it works.

Comment: I see that you're creating a **single** atom with `inputmany()` method. Why not rename it to `createAtom()` ?  Now you can see the importance of a good name. Read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/) naming conventions.